# Multiple Inheritance Class References

Tags: c++, class, multiple-inheritance, virtual-functions

Suppose I have a pair of base classes:

```
class A
{};

class B
{
    virtual void foo(A* ref);
    virtual void foo2(A* ref);
};
```

And from them, a few derived classes:

```
class C : virtual public A
{
   int data;
};

class D : public B
{
    virtual void foo(A* ref)
    {
        ((C*) (ref)).data = 5;
    }
};

class E : virtual public A
{
    int otherData;
};

class F : public B
{
    virtual void foo2(A* ref)
    {
        ((E*) (ref)).otherData = 6;
    }
};
```

And finally, we have a class that follows suit, as such:

```
class G : public E, public C
{
};
```

with a main function that goes as follows:

```
int main()
{
   B* myD = new D();
   B* myF = new F();

   A* myA = new G();

   myD->foo(myA);
   myF->foo2(myA);

   return 0;
}
```

Ok, IGNORING the obvious fact that this is a 'dreaded diamond' (which, the "multiple As" problem has been averted due to `virtual`), the general idea is that I want to have all my objects be Gs, Ds and Fs, but stored as references to As and Bs.  I want to be able to use B's (which is actually always either D or F) virtual functions to modify the values of G...  However, A and B do not know of any of their child classes, and thus cannot be declared using them.  This means that the virtual function arguments must always be a pointer to an A.  However, D wants to have it's input always be a C, and F wants it's input to be an E.  While this might not have been an issue if G was inheriting from only one parent, our current G is inheriting from 2 parents;  I do not know how the `this` pointers actually work in the underlying context of situations like this... however, I do not feel like this is going to be a possible situation.

Would anyone be willing to shed some light on the mechanisms of casting pointers to parent/child classes, and if there would be any way this could be pulled off?

Comment: Actually, what I dread here is not the diamond, it is: 1/ the use of unchecked pointers => please pass `ref` by reference and 2/ the use of C-casts => please use appropriate C++ casts (here probably with a runtime check)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have RTTI switched on, which you most likely do, you can use **dynamic_cast** to attempt to up-cast a base class pointer to a derived (or sibling) class pointer.  The referenced object is tested at runtime to see if it is a compatible class, if this is not a valid upcast than it will return 0, in which case you can test for that and branch.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_cast

Answer (score 1):

Since `A` is a virtual base of `G`, you cannot convert a pointer to `A` to a pointer to `G` statically. The whole meaning of `virtual` is "determined at runtime", and so the nature of the `A`-subobject to which you have a pointer can only be known at runtime. For example, in your case consider:

```
A * p = new G, q = new C;
```

Now both `p` and `q` point to *some* `A`-subobject, but the nature of the most-derived object in which they are contained is only determined by the actual most derived type. Thus it is impossible to have one single, fixed conversion rule from `A*` to `G*` or from `A*` to `C*`.

The only way to perform the cast is dynamically, i.e. via `dynamic_cast<C*>(p)` etc.

(By contrast, in non-virtual inheritance it is always known how a subobject relates to its more-derived objects, and thus pointers *can* be converted statically. There may be issues of naming ambiguity if you have multiple repeated bases, but there's no issue with locating the base subobjects.)

Answer (score 0):

As Kerrek and Andrew say, you should use `dynamic_cast`. However, if the children of `A` are static, you could use a different trick, which might be faster than `dynamic_cast` (since it doesn't depend on RTTI, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050901/performance-of-dynamic-cast) for more information).

```
class C;
class D;
class E;
class F;

class A
{
public:
    virtual C * isC () { return 0; }
    virtual E * isE () { return 0; }
};

class C : virtual public A
{
    friend class D;
    int data;
    C * isC () { return this; }
};

class E : virtual public A
{
    friend class F;
    int otherData;
    E * isE () { return this; }
};
```

Now, `D` and `F` can query `A` to see if `isC` or `isE` returns a valid pointer.

Comment: It mostly depend on how RTTI is internally implemented, but, for many platform what you describe is no more-no less than how dynamic_cast is actually implemented (the functions are implicitly added to a parallel object hierarchy). So I would not expect any particular performance difference.

Unless a particular inefficiency of the compiler, of course!

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050901/performance-of-dynamic-cast) out, in particular VladV's answer.