# How to store different objects in an array and get an object of a certain type?

Tags: c++, types, enums, casting

You may have heard of the [Entity Component System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93component%E2%80%93system), where everything is an `Entity` and each entity has a list of `Component`s which control its functionality.

I am trying to find out how to store different objects (each inherit `Component`) in an array and be able to get an object out of that array based on their type.

The first solution I can think of would be to have an `enum` for the types of objects inheriting component:

```
enum ComponentType : unsigned char    // There will never be more than 256 components
{
    EXAMPLE_COMPONENT,
    ANOTHER_EXAMPLE_COMPONENT,
    AND_ANOTHER_EXAMPLE_COMPONENT
};
```

Then `Component` base class has a `ComponentType type;` with a getter, and each child component sets its type e.g:

```
ExampleComponent::ExampleComponent()
{
    type = EXAMPLE_COMPONENT;
}
```

And then I'd have a `GetComponent` function:

```
Component* Entity::GetComponent(ComponentType type)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_components.size(); i++)
    {
        if (m_components.at(i).GetType() == type)
        {
            return &m_components.at(i);
        }
    }

    return nullptr;
}

// Note: m_components is an std::vector;
```

And then finally you would call `GetComponent` e.g:

```
(ExampleComponent*) component = entity.GetComponent(EXAMPLE_COMPONENT);
```

The problem with this is that you need an `enum` for each type of component and you also have to cast the component after using `GetComponent` to make sure you can access its own member variables.

Does anyone know of a proper way of doing this where there is no need for an `enum` and there is no need to cast the component? If there is a solution that still requires a type variable to be stored in each component it preferably would be a byte and can't be any bigger than 4 bytes.

**Edit:** I also don't want to use templates

Thanks in advance!

David

Comment: I'd replace the raw loop in `Entity::GetComponent` with `std::find_if` and a lambda. I'd also change the use of `NULL` to `nullptr` and get rid of the C style cast `(ExampleComponent*)` and replace it with a proper C++ cast. Also; `void*`'s are nasty - why not return a base class pointer instead..?

Comment: template and `dynamic_cast` ?

Comment: To me it seems your `enum` simulates polymorphism. Use real polymorphism by creating derived classes.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes, I should have done that. I edited my question

Comment: @Jarod42 I forgot to mention that I don't want to use templates. I've edited my question.

Comment: @KingThrushbeard The problem with polymorphism is that my different classes can't have different data that can be accessed without casting to the correct pointer. (Or am I wrong here?)

Comment: BTW: templates provide "compile-time polymorphism", derived classes provide "run-time polymorphism". You want the latter.

Comment: @DavidCallanan: Then, as Jarod42 said: use `dynamic_cast` on the caller side to do a down-cast. Alternatively, your base class could have a "fat interface".

Comment: check out this link you may get your accurate answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559412/how-to-store-different-data-types-in-one-list-c

Comment: @KingThrushbeard Does this mean I can loop through each component and try cast it, if it returns null then that component does not match the type? Also, would this cast be slow? And doesn't casting always work if they are casted to a derived class?

Comment: Yes, it would work, given that you compile your code to support "run-time-type information". E.g. with `g++` you must not use the `-fno-rtti` compiler option. I would not expect "best permformance", see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050901/performance-of-dynamic-cast. Part of the best answer to that question is the statement 'I know you didn't want to talk about this, but "a design where dynamic_cast is used a lot" is probably an indicator that you're doing something wrong...'

Comment: Proper way is to inherit from a base class, and implement necessary functionality through virtual functions. Then you do not need `enum` and would not need `GetComponent` function at all. They are part of your improper design.

Comment: Note: using all UPPERCASE identifiers for compile time constants is antipattern and should be avoided.

Comment: @Slava My `Component` classes most likely won't have any functions, because they are to store data, and each `Component` class will require a different amount of space to store this data.

Comment: Then you already started wrong - in OO you do not design what data classes have, but what behavior. So you start to design procedural program and ask how to properly do OO with it. That's a wrong way from beginning.

Comment: @Slava I'm just trying to follow the design of Entity Component System | From wikipedia -> Component: the raw data for one aspect of the object. Implementations typically use Structs, Classes, or Associative Arrays

Comment: @DavidCallanan Why exactly do you not want to use templates?

Comment: In that design I do not see that you need a cast. First of all it will not work in your naive design due to data slicing. Second - as I see in that design you do not need different types, just container in `Component` class.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach simulates polymorphism: Having the `type` as a member and an `if` statement checking for that type is typically a indication to make use of a class hierarchy. You already stated that you want to use objects derived from the `Component`type, so you should also make proper use of polymorphism.

The second problem in your approach is that you want to filter for a "specific type", which more or less is equivalent to a downcast — i.e. a `dynamic_cast<>()`: When you pass a certain `ComponentType` to `Entity::GetComponent()`, it returns a pointer to `Component`, but the object behind that pointer is always an object of a specific derived class: In your example you always get an `ExampleComponent` object, when you pass `EXAMPLE_COMPONENT` to that function.

The following question arises then naturally: What do you want to do with the object returned by this function? You can only call methods from the `Component` interface/class, but no method from the derived class! So the downcast hardly makes sense at all (it would, if you would return a pointer to an object of a class derived from `Component`.

Here is how it looks like using polymorphism and with the downcast in the `getComponent()` method, returning a pointer to a derived class — note that the method is a template to conveniently implement this for every class derived from `Component`:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Component {
public:
    virtual std::string getType() = 0;
};

using ComponentContainer = std::vector<Component*>;

class AComponent : public Component { public: virtual std::string getType() { return "A"; }; };
class BComponent : public Component { public: virtual std::string getType() { return "B"; }; };
class CComponent : public Component { public: virtual std::string getType() { return "C"; }; };


class Entity {
public:
    template <typename T>
    T* getComponent();

    void putComponent(Component* c) { m_components.push_back(c); }

private:
    ComponentContainer m_components;
};


template<typename T>
T* Entity::getComponent()
{
    T* t = nullptr;
    for (auto i : m_components) {
        if ((t = dynamic_cast<T*>(i)) != nullptr)
            break;
    }

    return t;
}

int main()
{
    Entity e;
    e.putComponent(new AComponent{});
    e.putComponent(new BComponent{});

    Component* c;
    if ((c = e.getComponent<AComponent>()) != nullptr)
        std::cout << c->getType() << std::endl;

    // delete all the stuff
    return 0;
}
```

The heavy use of `dynamic_cast<>()` is problematic both from performance and from design point of view: It should only be used rarely, if ever.

So the design problem may be that everything is stored in a single container? You could instead use several containers, based on "behaviour". As behaviour is implemented in an ECS as a derived class or interface, a `getComponent()`-similar method of this entity would only return objects of certain (sub-)interfaces. These components would then all implement a given interface method, so the need for down-casting would be eliminated.

For example, given you have "drawable components", this suggests the hierarchy:

```
// Drawable interface
class DrawableComponent : public Component {
public:
    virtual void draw() const = 0;
};

// Drawable objects derive from DrawableComponent
class  DComponent : public DrawableComponent {
public:
    virtual void draw() const { /* draw the D component */ }
};
```

Then, an entity could have a container of `DrawableComponent` objects and you would just iterate over those objects and call `draw()` on each:

```
using DrawableContainer = std::vector<DrawableComponent*>;
// m_drawables is a memober of Entity with above type
const DrawableContainer& Entity::getDrawables() { return m_drawables; }

// then just draw those objects
for (auto d : entity.getDrawables())
    d->draw(); // no downcast!
```

Comment: I'd definitely rather not use templates or `dynamic_cast`. The components will not have any functionality though, they are only for data. And I won't have any components that are inheriting `DrawableComponent`. It will just be loads of different components e.g `DrawableComponent`, `TransformComponent`, `PhysicsComponent` that store different data about the entity. And then systems take in entities with certain components and do functionality which may change the data of a component.